# Need to search the file from DB based on text

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, indexing, ifilter

How is it possible to search the file from the set of files which have been uploaded in the ms-sql DB based on the text entered by the user. The file could be of any type like .txt, .pdf, .doc, .jpeg. How does indexing works in this scenario. How can I implement this functionality. Want to implement this functionality for ASP.NET based web application

Answer (score 0):

You can implement full text indexing.  You will need to have a relevant filter for each file type uploaded.

Comment: Hi Mike,Thanks a lot for replying. I am new to this. Can you please provide any links or reference on how to implement this.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15391/Full-Text-Indexing-Files-with-Microsoft-SQL-Server - It's a bit old but covers the basics I think.